# Make variables from JSON array from Stripe

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I am using PHP to return an array for a customer object in Stripe. Here's an example of what this array looks like:

```
Stripe\Customer JSON: {
"id": "censored",
"object": "customer",
"account_balance": 0,
"created": 1447428085,
"currency": "usd",
"default_source": "censored",
"delinquent": false,
"description": "From website",
"discount": null,
"email": "email@email.com",
"livemode": false,
"metadata": {
    "First_Last": "asdf asdf",
    "Info": "|Make: maketest |Model: modeltest |serial: 1 |YOM: 1999",
    "Shipping_firstaddr": "asdf asdf",
    "Shipping_lastaddr": "asdf",
    "Shipping_country": "CA",
    "Shipping_zip": "asdf",
    "Shipping_city": "asdf",
    "Shipping_states": "AK",
    "Shipping_mobile": "asdf",
    "Same_as_billing?": "Yes",
    }
```

}

I now need to pull out the values in metadata->Info such that each item inbetween the pipes is a variable with a value. For example, it would be ideal to have a variable, like $make, equal the value in the pipe, in this case "maketest".

EDIT: Thus far I have isolated the "Info" from the array into a variable. If I were to echo that variable it would say "|Make: maketest |Model: modeltest |serial: 1 |YOM: 1999"

EDIT 2: I have not yet tried any code to do anything with this variable. Honestly, I don't know where to start. RegEx? I don't know RegEx, but happy to learn if that's best.

EDIT 3: So I did google stuff before posting this, but I couldn't find the right thing. Thanks to help from comments I googled the right thing and figured out a solution that will work.

Comment: Cool. Can you share what you've tried and the problems that you've had?

Comment: Thus far I have isolated "Info" from the array into a variable. So if I echo'd that variable, it would read "|Make: maketest |Model: modeltest |serial: 1 |YOM: 1999"
@JayBlanchard
I'm thinking about learning RegEx to get this done?

Comment: Edit your question to show what code you've tried!

Comment: @miken32 I haven't tried any yet because I honestly don't know where to start... I edited.

Comment: I'd start by searching Google for "php variable from json" and I'd be very surprised if your answer wasn't in the top 5 hits. JSON decoding is built into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to list things out into variables and it works!
$info is a variable that has the "Info" from the metadata, so echo'd it would be "|Make: maketest |Model: modeltest |serial: 1 |YOM: 1999"

Then just do

```
list($Make, $Model,$Serial, $YOM)=explode('|',$info);
var_dump($Make);
var_dump($Model);
var_dump($Serial);
var_dump($YOM);
```

This results in listing these variables such that $Make = "Make: maketest"

It's not ideal, but I can work with this.